# LMM (nested data) -> Heteroscedasticity

Tags: r, heteroscedasticity

I want to apply the lmer function to test some fixed factors (treatment, body size of females, body size of males) and some random effects (females, males, location of male, location of female) on the Response variable (egg volume). Females and female sizes seem to have a significant effect on the egg volume. However, when I plotted egg volume ~ sire length, I recognized heteroscedasticity which was confirmed by a Breusch-Pagan test.

As I'm new in stats and even newer to R: how do I deal with this issue? What does that mean / imply for my model? my data sample is quit big (around 3000 eggs).

Thanks for any help!
Rebekka

Comment: I don't understand "when I plotted egg volume ~ sire length, I recognized heteroscedasticity". You have many other covariates (and even state that females are significant!) which might remove this when included in the model. Why do you focus on such a parsimonious model?

Comment: Because I didn't know better. I'm not a pro in stats and even less in R :-/

Comment: Well, generally it is good practice to start with a full model ...